# is there a way to concatenate multiple variables into one?

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

I am trying to create a concatenated variable/css property.

what im trying to achieve: 
For given n images with width 300px, I want to achieve this

Is this possible in scss/sass?

```
$n: 8;
$width: 300px;

background: url('https://image1.jpg') no-repeat, ..., url('https://imagesN.jpg') no-repeat;
background-position: 0, 300px, 600px, ..., n * width;
```